# postgresql - find a row with data value less than in previous row

Tags: postgresql

I need to find a row with data value less than in previous row. The best - next row. I prefer to use single SELECT query than stored procedure.

Sample of data:

```
1
3
5
8
7
6
10
11
16
15
14
13
```

So the best I'd find the row with value 6. I can modify table structure to add any required column. Data is bulk inserted from external file and I have full control over this process.

Comment: Rows in a relational database are not sorted, and thus there is no concept of a "next" or "previous" row unless you can define some sort order. You have only shown a single (unnamed) column. You have to have some column that defines the sort order of those values, otherwise this cannot be solved.

Comment: Originally I do have an ordering column in my data. I haven't add it here not to disturb the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need some means to order your rows. Otherwise it's not possible to tell which row is previous.

Once you have an ordering column, you can use [lag()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) function to accomplish your task:

```
postgres=# create table tbl(id serial, val numeric);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# insert into tbl(val) values (1),(3),(5),(8),(7),(6),(10),(11),(16),(15),(14),(13);
INSERT 0 12

postgres=# select * from tbl order by id;
 id | val 
----+-----
  1 |   1
  2 |   3
  3 |   5
  4 |   8
  5 |   7
  6 |   6
  7 |  10
  8 |  11
  9 |  16
 10 |  15
 11 |  14
 12 |  13
(12 rows)

postgres=# select val
postgres-# from   (
postgres(#          select val, lag(val) over (order by id) prev_val
postgres(#          from   tbl
postgres(#        ) t
postgres-# where  val < prev_val;
 val 
-----
   7
   6
  15
  14
  13
(5 rows)
```